# How to get NSString (Unix style path) from FSSpec

Tags: cocoa, unix, nsstring

How to get NSString (Unix style path) from FSSpec

Regards,
Dhana.

Comment: You should mark some of the answers you have received as correct to thank the prople who help you

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an FSRef for the FSSpec.
2. [Create a CFURL for the FSRef](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateFromFSRef).
3. Copy or get an NSString of the URL's file-system path, using either [the `CFURLCopyFileSystemPath` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCopyFileSystemPath) or [the `-[NSURL path]` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path).

Don't forget to release the CFURL, [since you Created it](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/). The same goes for the path, if you Copied it.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will work fine..

If wrong please modify..

```
char * UnixPathFromFSSpec(FSSpec *sfile)
{
    char unixPath[2048];
    unixPath[0] = '\0';
    FSRef ref;

    if(FSpMakeFSRef(sfile, &ref) == noErr )
    {
        FSRefMakePath(&ref, unixPath, sizeof(unixPath));
    }

    return unixPath;
}
```

Comment: Use `PATH_MAX` rather than hard-coding a number of bytes. You may also want to return `NULL` if either function fails, instead of returning an empty string; moreover, you've declared the array as a local variable, which means that it will stop existing when the function exits. You really should return an NSString instead of a C string.